# How to return and pass array's?

Tags: python, arrays

```
def main():

    ran = fillaray()
    totalOdds(ran)


def fillaray():
    size = 10
    num = [0] * size
    import random
    for index in range(size):
        var = random.randint(0,9)
        num[index] = var
        return num


def totalOdds(ran):
    print(ran)
```

I'm trying to fill "num" with 10 random integers and then return it back into main.  I'm not familiar with returning and passing array's so I've ran into a problem.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Benjamin found your actual bug; you return on the first time through the loop.  But just to help you out, here's how a Python programmer would more typically write your fillarray() function:

```
import random
def fillarray(size = 10):
    return [random.randint(0,9) for i in range(size)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the array after just filling up 1 value. Your return statement should be outside the for loop. fillarray() can alternatively written as-

```
def fillarray():
    size = 10
    import random
    num = [random.randint(0,9) for i in range(size)]
    return num
```

Comment: Thanks guys.  I should've noticed that one.

Appreciate the help.